# ScheduledExecutorService force run task immediately

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

I am running ScheduledExecutorService with scheduleWithFixedDelay of 5 Minutes. Assigned runnable task to ScheduledExecutorService submit tasks to ThreadPoolExecutor. I am using ArrayBlockingQueue (taskQueue) of size 1 for ThreadPoolExecutor.

I wanted to say to ScheduledExecutorService that my thread pool don't have any task to do now. All thread are free. So please don't wait for 5 Minutes and call runnable task immediately.

Is there any way to do it.

Comment: This is not what a `ScheduledExecutorService` does - it simply runs a task every interval. What you want seems to be some sort of task queue that runs tasks when idle - this is more complicated.

Comment: Please suggest if any existing java implementation or any better approach for the same.

Comment: There really isn't enough information in your (very short and unclear) question to give any recommendations. For example, if the code is supposed to run the task immediately; where does the 5 minutes come in?